# Is there any non-recursive term that folds over a scott-encoded list?

Tags: haskell, recursion, lambda-calculus, church-encoding, scott-encoding

Suppose that I have a [scott-encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Mogensen%E2%80%93Scott_encoding&oldid=647390899) list such as:

```
scott = (\ c n -> c 1 (\ c n -> c 2 (\ c n -> c 3 (\ c n -> n))))
```

I want a function that receives such kind of list and converts it to an actual list (`[1,2,3]`), except that such function can not be recursive. That is, it must be in eta-beta normal form. Does that function exist?

Comment: For that specific list, yes it exists. But you surely mean a function which can take _any_ such list, arbitrarily long, and returns a standard list, right?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `\c n -> c 3 (\c n -> n)` in the end of the list?

Comment: The types of scott-encoded lists are not uniform - that is, the type changes each time you apply another "cons cell". You would need a type class to do this, otherwise the hypothetical `toList` function is ill-typed.

Comment: @user2407038 Indeed. I think this is more about the untyped lambda calculus than Haskell.

Comment: @chi well, someone convinced me ULC questions are still relevant to Haskell since that's still what you use when, for example, doing type-level computations, or writing DSLs.

Comment: I have a feeling that there's no such a term, but I have no idea about how to prove that.

Comment: I agree. Intuitively, it doesn't make sense, indeed... but without a proof it is hard to know for sure.

Comment: Can't we do something with the fact that `newtype SList a = SList (forall r. r -> (a -> SList a -> r) -> r)` is not strictly positive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I give it a shot. Feel free to correct me, because I'm not an expert on this.

For arbitrary `x` and `xs`, it must be the case that `toList (\c n -> c x xs)` reduces to a term that is convertible to `x : toList xs`.

This is only possible if we reduce the left hand side to `c x xs` by applying `(\c n -> c x xs)` to some `c` and `n`. So `toList ~ (\f -> f ? ?)`. (BTW, this is the part where I couldn't think of a nice rigorous argument; I had some ideas but none very nice. I'd be happy to hear tips).

Now it must be the case that `c x xs ~ (x : toList xs)`. But since `x` and `xs` are distinct universal variables, and they are the only variables occurring in the right hand side, the equation is in [Miller's pattern fragment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_(computer_science)#Higher-order_unification), and therefore `c ~ (\x xs -> x : toList xs)` is its most general solution.

So, `toList` must reduce to `(\f -> f (\x xs -> x : toList xs) n)` for some `n`. Clearly, `toList` can't have a normal form, since we can always unfold the recursive occurrence.

Comment: I don't get the Miller's pattern fragment part, but it looks very correct to me.

Comment: Disclaimer: I'm (obviously) not completely sure this is correct.